# I'm getting wrong Json format while converting xml to Json and returning back in WCF

Tags: json, wcf

I'm using code as below

```
string strFetchResData = string.Empty;
        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();

        double RateId = 299;
        bool UseNetMetering = true;
        string StartTime = "2/26/2008%2011:00:00%20AM";
        string EndTime = "2/26/2009%2010:00:00%20AM";

        using (var client = new CookieAwareWebClient())
        {
            Uri uri = new Uri("https://www.myServiceUrl.com/Services.svc/SynthesizedBill?RateId=" + RateId + "&UseNetMetering=" + UseNetMetering + "&StartTime=" + StartTime + "&EndTime=" + EndTime + "");
            client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CPRUserName"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CPRPassword"]);
            strFetchResData = client.DownloadString(uri);
        }

        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml(strFetchResData);
        objSynthesizedData.PowerBill = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(doc).Replace(@"@", @"").Remove(1, 44);
```

am Using Data member as

```
[DataContract]
public class SynthesizedPowerBill
{
    [DataMember]
    public string PowerBill { get; set; }
}
```

but I'm not getting the output in json format,
[image]

Why the format is not coming in JSON format? it is coming like a normal string, i want json format.
please help me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a DataContractJsonSerializer instead?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb410770(v=vs.110).aspx